# Contagem de tempo Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela onde faz a contagem do tempo de conexões dos cliente no `freeradios`, toda hora que o cliente entra ou sai da rede ele registra. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para saber quanto tempo cada usuário navegou por dia de forma distinta no MySQL.

EX:

```
fulanoA: 1000
FulanoB: 1728
FulanoC: 12
```

A tabela é a seguinte

```
CREATE TABLE `radacct`
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctsessiontime` int(12) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Comment: Defina "navegou por dia de forma distinta".

Comment: Amigo, sua tabela não registra o necessário, você só tem o tempo de entrada do usuário? E quando ele saí? Você não registra? Como você pretende calcular o tempo de conexão deles sem essa informação?

Comment: Na acctsessiontime fica segundos que ele permaneceu conectado

Answer (score 2):

```
Select username, Sum(acctsessiontime) as tempo_logado from radacct Group By username
```

assim você terá um listagem por usuário, quantos segundos ele ficou.